# Importing content from a Word document into SharePoint

Tags: publishing-site, best-practices, word

We have some content in Word documents that we need to convert to web pages (publishing) in SharePoint. I know there are many ways to do this, with advantages and disadvantages. I would really like to hear your views on what is the best method to do this with a minimum amount of re-editing but also in such a way that you do not end up with outrageously bad HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this once for 2007, but I must confess I've not tried for 2010.

The best advice I can give based on my 2007 experience is:

- to create [a Word Template that
  restricts the styles](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/04/01/restrict-or-permit-formatting-changes-in-word-documents/) a user can
  use.
- [avoid images](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/04/18/document-conversion-service-and-images/) entirely.
- don't be afraid to consider 3rd party
  converters - or writing your own.
- if you've already got those Word files
  full of content, you're probably
  stuck. (This is what killed the
  project I'd been working on. They
  **had** to have a consistent style, but had slapped tonnes of content
  into hundreds of Word files already)

Answer (score 1):

Create a Blog under your main Site and use Windows Live Writer 2011 to compose your document and its images.

- If there are no images use Live's
  Source pane and copy and paste into
  your HTML view of your RTF section in
  your List or Wiki.

  If there are images, publish to to
  your Blog (set to read-only for
  everyone). The images and thumbs (and
  HTML) are then part of your Site and
  can be used as copy and paste
  anywhere you need them.

Also use an HTML/CSS editor to set up your required formatting and bring across the CSS as in-line or use a CEWP to hold the CSS or reference to the same.

Comment: Now that Windows Liver Writer has been discontinued, use Open Live Writer now instead: http://openlivewriter.org/